# Starting out with OOP -Dice game question

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to grasp object oriented programming (OOP). 
I am making a die game, but I am a little stuck -

```
package ch6CLASSES;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class getDie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A simple dice game.");
    int COUNT =10;

    for (int i=0;i<COUNT;i++) {
    Die userDie = new Die();
    System.out.println("user: "+userDie.getValue());

    Die computerDie = new Die();
    System.out.println("computer: "+computerDie.getValue());

    System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

So I have another class where I calculated everything - but now my question is... within the for loop I had I would like to make a running count of how many times the computer or user wins after each round, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to have some way to determine whether the computer or user wins. (Since you are practicing OOP a method would probably be most appropriate) Looking at your code it looks like each `Die` will only have one value, so you have to keep recreating objects. I would recommend having a `roll()` method that would return a random number between 1 and 6. That way you wouldn't have to create new objects on each iteration of the loop.

Second you'll need a method to determine is the user won. One easy way to do this would be to have the method accept an `int` parameter and then compare it to the value of the current `Die` object. Here are some code to get you started in the right direction:

```
public int roll() {
   //generate random number
}

public boolean wonRoll(int value) {
     if(this.getValue() > value) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

And then in your loop:

```
int computerWins = 0;
int userWins = 0;
Die userDie = new Die();
Die computerDie = new Die();
for (int i=0;i<COUNT;i++) {

    System.out.println("user: "+userDie.getValue());  
    System.out.println("computer: "+computerDie.getValue());
    if(userDie.wonRoll(computerDie.getValue()) {
        userWins++;
    } else {
        computerWins++;
    }

}
System.out.println("Computer won " + computerWins + " many times");
System.out.println("User won " + userWins + " many times");
```